# How to make inference with Huggingface deep learning container from Lambda using Serverless framework

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

This is a question from ML newbee :-)

I am building AWS StepFunction with Serverless framework and one of the steps is intended to deploy a Sagemaker endpoint with HuggingFace deep learning container (DLC).

The problem is that I could not make Lambda to work with SageMaker (to build estimator).

One of the solutions I have is to manually launch the endpoint using the SageMaker studio, but I really want to have everything within the code.

Here is what I am trying to do to get Sagemaker working

```py
def installPack(package):
    import subprocess
    import sys
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

installPack('sagemaker')
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel
import sagemaker 

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
        'HF_MODEL_ID':'distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad', # model_id from hf.co/models
        'HF_TASK':'question-answering' # NLP task you want to use for predictions
        }

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = sagemaker.HuggingFaceModel(
            env=hub,
            role=role, # iam role with permissions to create an Endpoint
            transformers_version="4.6", # transformers version used
            pytorch_version="1.7", # pytorch version used
            py_version="py36", # python version of the DLC

..........
```

The error I'm getting is

```
WARNING: The directory '/home/sbx_user1051/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
```

*(... then there are many lines of log like Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)...*

```
Downloading pox-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting multiprocess>=0.70.12
Downloading multiprocess-0.70.12.2-py38-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for sagemaker, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for protobuf3-to-dict, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dill, zipp, pytz, pyparsing, protobuf, ppft, pox, numpy, multiprocess, smdebug-rulesconfig, protobuf3-to-dict, pathos, pandas, packaging, importlib-metadata, google-pasta, attrs, sagemaker
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer found:

1. API is deployed using Sagemaker studio like described [here](https://github.com/C24IO/SageMaker-HuggingFace-Workshop/blob/main/inference/lab1_deploy_transformer_model_from_s3/1_deploy_transformer_model_from_s3.ipynb)

2. The inference code from Lambda is this:

```py
    import os, io, boto3, json

    ENDPOINT_NAME = "huggingface-pytorch-inference-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

    inputs = {'inputs': {
                        'question': 'What is used for inference?',
                        'context': 'My Name is Philipp and I live in Nuremberg. This model is used with sagemaker for inference.'}
    }
    payload = json.dumps(inputs, indent=2).encode('utf-8')

    print(f"payload: {type(payload)}, {payload}")
        
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                        ContentType='text/csv',
                                        Body=payload)
```